# Make a border inside a table with CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to make a border inside a table with CSS like it is shown in the picture. Left side is what I have and the right side shows the border that I need.

[Here is](https://jsfiddle.net/mozghovyi/0gzp3jb1/) the fiddle where I am trying to do this.

At first, I thought to do this with

```
border-top: 1px solid rgb(72, 170, 230);
```

and border-left etc. styles applied to the outer cells. It works only for the cells that do not have other cells on that side. But if they have a neighbor border-"side" does not work.

[image: What I need]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rowspan` and `colspan` you can perform.

HTML

```
<td class="inner-table" rowspan="4" colspan="4">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="mainTable"></td>
          <td class="mainTable"></td>
          <td class="mainTable"></td>
          <td class="mainTable"></td>
        </tr>
```

CSS

```
.inner-table{
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgb(72, 170, 230);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0gzp3jb1/2/

Comment: thank you, this almost solves the problem for me. There are just two issues: such solution breaks the layout because the cells become of different size and secondly we indicate the number of cells statically, but this will be a dynamic table that will shrink or expand depending on the actions of the user...

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that you are searching for border "double"

```
.div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
border: 10px double black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9qw925d5/2/
`

Comment: sorry, but this solution does not work in my case. Thank you for the suggestion though.